# Why do I need to press Enter twice after getline()?

Tags: c++, c++17, getline

Everything is working fine in this program except when it reaches `getline()` after `cout<<"From Date: ";`. At this point no matter if I give input or simply hit enter without input, I have to hit enter twice to proceed further. I tried removing `cin.ignore()` but it causes more problem by jumping over the first `getline()`. Here is the snippet which is causing this problem-

```
int main() {
  Date d1;
  int choice;
  cout << "\nEnter choice: ";
  cin >> choice;
  cin.ignore(numeric_limits < streamsize > ::max(), '\n');
  switch (choice) {
  case 1:
    d1.diffbw();
    break;
  default:
    cout << "Wrong choice";
  }
  return 0;
}

void Date::diffbw() {
  Date current, ref;
  string choice;
  cout << "\n  Type 'man' to enter date manually else hit Enter to insert current date!";
  do {
    cout << "From Date:";
    getline(cin, choice);
    if (choice == "man")
      current.getdate(); //getdate() assigns day, month and year in object current
    else if (choice.empty())
      current = sysDate(); //sysDate returns system date
    else {
      cout << "\n  Wrong Choice!";
      cout << "\n  Enter Again?(y/n): ";
      getline(cin, choice);
    }
  } while (choice == "y" || choice == "Y");

  do {
    cout << "To Date:";
    getline(cin, choice);
    if (choice.empty())
      ref = sysDate();
    else if (choice == "man")
      ref.getdate();
    else {
      cout << "\n  Wrong Choice!";
      cout << "\n  Enter Again?(y/n): ";
      getline(cin, choice);
    }
  } while (choice == "y" || choice == "Y");

  current.calcAge(ref); //calcAge() calculates difference between two given dates.
  cout << "\n  Difference: ";
  cout << abs(current.day) << " day(s) " << abs(current.month) << " month(s) " << abs(current.year) << " year(s)";
}
```

P.S.- I am using g++ compiler on windows.

**Edit: I posted the whole function here as many people are having difficulty in understanding the context here. I also corrected the 'cin.ignore()' syntax as suggested by @john. I am trying to calculate difference between two given dates.**

The second 'do while' loop works without any bug although it is completely synonymous with the first one.

Comment: You are using `cin.ignore` incorrectly. ignore should be used **after** input when you know there is input you wish to discard. It should not be used **before** input when you cannot know what the state of the input stream is.

Comment: If you use Linux, you might consider using [GNU readline](https://www.gnu.org/software/readline/). The input line is then editable. Otherwise, what should happen when your program is inside some [pipeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)) ?

Comment: Try adding a `<< std::flush` at the end of those `cout` lines.

Comment: @dxiv unless you've explicitly disabled it attempting to read from cin automatically flushes cout

Comment: read [getline](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/)

Comment: Please provide a [mre], what are you doing before this code?

Comment: @AlanBirtles That's a fair point, so I just left the "*try*" part.

Comment: @john Thanks for pointing out. I corrected that in my code but that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: @dxiv I tried using std::flush. Not helping.

Comment: This might not answering your question, but you might want to place the `cin.ignore()` after entering [integral types](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/references/unix/digital/AQTLTBTE/DOCU_032.HTM), not inside the function.

Comment: @PracticalMinds The problem here is that your bug depends on the state of the input stream which we cannot know just from a snippet of your code. In any case this is just the normal bug caused by careless mixing of numeric input and getline. It's easy to solve if you understand what the problem is. So I suggest you read up on the many discussions of the issue and apply the correct approach to reading your input.

Comment: @PracticalMinds For instance this code is **wrong** `cout<<"\nEnter choice: "; cin>>choice;`. This is exactly what I was saying, use ignore after you do numeric input. You aren't doing that here.

Comment: @PracticalMinds The bottom line is that you have to understand the problem, why is ignore necessary in some cases. Just blindly trying to apply a solution you've seen in a different context is unlikely to work. Plus at least in the code you've posted ignore is being called wrongly. It shouldn't be `cin.ignore();`, it should be `cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');`

Comment: I replaced 'getline()' with 'cin' and it solved my problem but I want 'getline()' to work.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you are first trying to get a value by calling cin.getline() and afterwards the program is done but is waiting for confirmation and it gets the confirmation by you pressing enter.

Basically

```
Enter Value: 5 //Presses enter
Press any key to exit window.
```

Comment: Program is clearly not done here. There is an if block following that getline() so it should carry on executing. Shouldn't it?

Comment: @PracticalMinds: we don't understand your program, because you did not provide any [mre]. And on many operating systems, `getline` is a blocking input operation. On Linux, you might consider using [poll(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) to wait for a finite amount of time the user input

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Sorry for my mistakes, I just joined stackoverflow. I will try to learn more about them.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement

```
cout<<"\n\n  From Date:";
```

is strange and probably wrong, since the `std::cout` stream is generally buffered.

You should use `std::cout << "From date:" << std::endl;` and read a good [C++ programming book](https://www.stroustrup.com/programming.html) and check in [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) that you are correctly using every function or feature from the C++ standard library.

If you compile with a recent [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), I recommend enabling all warnings and debug info, so compiling with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`. Then use your debugger, e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/).

If your computer runs some Linux or POSIX system, you could be interested in using [GNU readline](https://www.gnu.org/software/readline/): then the input line becomes user-editable. You might also want to code a graphical application with [Qt](https://qt.io/).

> Everything is working fine in this program

How did you check that? What debugger did you use? What test cases do you have? Did you try to type something with spaces, e.g. `today's date` as the user input? What did happen?

Comment: I tried correcting cout syntax but that doesn't help it. I don't know how to use a debugger but will try learn soon. I know my program is working fine as I tested almost all the cases(that i know of) manually. I am using a g++ compiler on windows 10.

Comment: Yes I tried two arguments with spaces and that rightfully redirects to the else part showing "wrong choice". But this time it is not asking for an extra enter key.

Answer (score 0):

I slightly modified your program to avoid relying on the Date class, which you did not define:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
void diffbw();

int main() {
  int choice;
  cout << "\nEnter choice: ";
  cin >> choice;
  cin.ignore(numeric_limits < streamsize > ::max(), '\n');
  switch (choice) {
  case 1:
    diffbw();
    break;
  default:
    cout << "Wrong choice";
  }
}

void diffbw() {
  string choice;
  cout << "\n  Type 'man' to enter date manually else hit Enter to insert current date!";
  do {
    cout << "From Date:";
    getline(cin, choice);
    cout << "choice";
    if (choice == "man") {
    }
    else if (choice.empty()) {
    }
    else {
      cout << "\n  Wrong Choice!";
      cout << "\n  Enter Again?(y/n): ";
      getline(cin, choice);
    }
  } while (choice == "y" || choice == "Y");

  do {
    cout << "To Date:";
    getline(cin, choice);
    if (choice.empty()) {
    }
    else if (choice == "man") {
    }
    else {
      cout << "\n  Wrong Choice!";
      cout << "\n  Enter Again?(y/n): ";
      getline(cin, choice);
    }
  } while (choice == "y" || choice == "Y");

  cout << "\n  Difference: ";
}
```

and I don't see the same phenomenon you describe. That is, I don't need to press Enter twice. Please consider making your problematic program more minimal, and at the same time complete.

Comment: Thanks I will consider from next time.

Comment: What I can infer from this code is that the problem lies within the 'if' and 'else if' block functions i.e. 'getdate()' and 'sysDate()' but I tried replacing 'getline()' with 'cin>>' in original code and it solved the problem.